# is it possilbe to stop the NSTimer before it reach the specified time?

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I am using a timer with `repeats: false` so it does run one time, in that one time run before reaching the time delay I want to stop executing the timer.

```
    timer?.invalidate()
    timer = nil 
    //is not working
```

the below code snippet is the sample I tried

```
  var timer : Timer?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        timer = Timer()
    }

    @IBAction func startAction(_ sender: Any) {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10.0, repeats: false, block: { (make) in
            print("ack did")
        })
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func cancelAction(_ sender: Any) {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
```

so here first I am tapping on start, so the timer starts and wait for specified 10 seconds,
i want that execution to stop when the user tap on cancel. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, and you've even shown the code to stop the timer. What you've posted will work.

Note that the line

```
    timer = Timer()
```

In your `viewDidLoad()` is pointless. Don't create a throw-away timer just to make your variable non-null